# Is it a good idea to get Akmagnus as a Magnus replacement?

Tags: ps4, warframe

So, I have a Magnus, and I want to know if it is a good idea to craft another one so I can get the dual-wield version, the Akmagnus. I like the Magnus, and I also liked Aklato. I need to know if it's a good idea.

Comment: This is primaraly opinion based. The AK-Variant usally looses some reload speed and accuarcy for a bigger clip and higher fire rate. If you prefer one set of stats over the other, then go for the one that increases the stats you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Akmagnus greatly outclasses it's single counterpart, as long as you don't mind losing some reload speed for it.

What it makes for is nearly double the magazine capacity of the single Magnus, a higher Crit Damage, higher Status Chance, and an innate 2x damage on headshots. The only downside, as previously mentioned, is a measley 50% longer reload time, but keep in mind, you're getting a double mag capacity (2 magnus's in each hand), so the setback is very small.